# Deleted python3 and python3.5. reinstalled in shell. Can't launch terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.5

In /usr/lib I did sudo rm -rf python3 and python3.5 for a dumb reason.

I tried ctrl+alt+F1 and then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-all
$ sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
$ sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

Terminal still won't launch.

Also tried:

```
$ sudo apt install --reinstall python3
```

but gets

```
"subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code(1)
```

I'm really not a linux user so I have no idea what I'm doing. What should I do to get terminal running again?

Comment: I won't say this is off topic, but it might be a better question for [Ask Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Why did you do this? You'll probably need to reinstall your system.

Comment: Are you getting any errors when trying to launch the terminal?

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/877398

Comment: @PrestonM no, just doesn't launch when clicked.

Comment: @Daniel-Roseman Because i'm a dummy and a novice.

Comment: @Fred-Larson I didn't know this was a thing, thanks! I tried this, but it gives errors. :(